# Concatenating multiple excels with same column names and sheets

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I have `40 files, 3 sheets`, `Happy, Still, Sad` and in each sheet the column titles are the same. 
I want to concatenate those 40 files so that each sheet will have the information of all 40 files.

#### for example:

in each file the column names are X Y Z 
When i concatenate, i need to have:

in

```
Happy X1 Y1 Z1 
      X2 Y2 Z2
      ...
      X40 Y40 Z40
```

and same in `Still` and `Sad`.

So how do I add the number for each column from `X` to `Xi`
and how to I concatenate them into 1 file.

this is what I have, i got it to put each new file on the right of the first, but i want them in columns,:

`

```
def concatenate(path = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Work\\subject", outfile = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Work\\subject\\concatenated.csv"):
    os.chdir(path)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.xlsx")
    dfList=[]
    i=1
    string = "subject"
    for files in fileList:
        df = pd.read_excel(files, sheet_name=None)
        cdf = pd.concat(df.values(), axis = 1) #concats the sheets into 1 page        
        sub = string + str(i) 
        cdf.to_csv((sub + ".csv"), encoding='utf-8', index=False)
        i+=1
        ColNames=[sub + "_happy",sub + "_happy",sub + "_happy",sub + "_happy",sub +"_still",sub +"_still",sub +"_still",sub +"_still",sub+"_sad",sub+"_sad",sub+"_sad",sub+"_sad"]
        cdf.columns=ColNames
        dfList.append(cdf)


    concatDf = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0, ignore_index=True, verify_integrity=True)
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index=None)`
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'll write it in the answers do it looks better

Comment: You can edit your question. And you should include what didn't work for you in your solution.